# Multiple File Selection For Uploading in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

There are several resources available on net to upload multiple files, 
but using multiple FileUpload controls. 
What I need to have multiple file selection dialog box so that user can select multiple files at one shot and then all files should be uploaded on one click.

Anyone of you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best client side browser library to upload multiple files over http?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159600/what-is-the-best-client-side-browser-library-to-upload-multiple-files-over-http)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to check out the Flajaxian controls - http://www.flajaxian.com/. They give you the ability to select multiple files at once for upload, and the control is free.

Comment: Erk.  I keep forgetting it's not 1999 any more.  :)

Comment: Thanks Paul McLean.

Thats a nice one. But I do need the filenames for other stuff such as storing thumbnails within database, saving the files with tempname as there are lots of files to be uploaded. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should know that this is impossible using just the normal html and javascript code, due to security issues in the browsers.

To do that you will need to use another external way such as:

Flash -> [SwfUpload](http://swfupload.org/), [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/)

Applet

ActiveX

Silverlight

Also check these questions:

[WebDev: What is the best way to do a multi-file upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97198/webdev-what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-multi-file-upload)

[Best way to upload multiple files from a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582126/best-way-to-upload-multiple-files-from-a-browser)

[ASP.net - Multiple Upload with jQuery Multiple File Upload Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562696/asp-net-multiple-upload-with-jquery-multiple-file-upload-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you'd have to do this with a Java applet (or ActiveX control) that pops up a file open dialog and then assigns each of the file names selected to a hidden FileUpload HTML control.