# Selecting Multiple Files for Upload in Web Page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, client

I am building a file upload web page that has the capability to process multiple upload files.  Ideally I would like to allow the user to select a folder and have the web page enumerate the files in the folder client-side, but I don't think that's possible without a browser plugin.

Alternatively, *would it be possible to allow the user to select multiple files in the File/Open dialog using Shift-click and Ctrl-click, and enumerate those*?

To be clear, I don't want the user to have to specify each file individually by repeatedly opening and closing a File/Open dialog.

I can't use Flash or any other type of binary plugin, but jQuery is OK.  I need to support IE7+, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222330/multiple-file-selection-for-uploading-in-asp-net/1222433  and my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222330/multiple-file-selection-for-uploading-in-asp-net/1222433#1222433

Comment: These appear to require flash.

Comment: yes, because there is no way without flash, silverlight or activex

Comment: You probably don't want to upload lots of files in one http request as it tends to become unreliable. After a while, you find you end up hitting various firewall request size limits, timeouts and general network issues. Most of the add-in up loaders will upload each file on a different request, which makes things more reliable and provides better error handling.

Comment: I plan to use Darren Johnstone's File Uploader control: darrenjohnstone.net/2008/08/…. It already knows how to handle multiple, large file uploads properly; I was just hoping to make it a little easier for the users to perform the multiple file selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend reading [this article](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/06/Using-the-HTML5-input-typefile-multiplemultiple-Tag-in-ASPNET)  by **Rick Strahl**

short answer for **HTML5**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
  <label>Upload Images:</label>
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="File1" id="File1" accept="image/*" />
  <hr />  
  <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload Images" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

> would it be possible to allow the user to select multiple files in the File/Open dialog using Shift-click and Ctrl-click, and enumerate those?

No.

Although actually, according to the HTML spec, file upload fields were originally *supposed* to allow it. Opera supported this in an older version, but it made many webapps that weren't expecting multiple files fall over, so they stopped it.

The only way to do it today is with a plugin, preferably a Flash uploader backed with multiple HTML single-file-upload controls as fallback.

Comment: I will use an "add file" button for the initial version. If user feedback says that multiple file selection is required, I will tell them that it requires a Flash or Java dependency.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

May want to try www.pulpload.com . Depending on the browser it could be a nice way to upload multiple files

Answer (score 0):

You need either Flash or Java to be able to select several files for upload.
Check this out: http://www.uploadify.com/
There are tons of [other solutions](http://www.google.ie/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=upload+multiple+files&btnG=Google+Search&meta=&aq=f&oq=)... But none is pure HTML.