# Cross-browser multiple file picking and uploading with authentication?

Tags: flash, authentication, file-upload, cross-browser

What's the simplest cross-browser way to do allow a web site user to do multiple file picking and uploading with "Negotiate" and/or basic authentication?  Although I am not too worried about IE6, I do need to support IE8, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome; ideally, I would support mobile browsers too.

- Using a Flash uploader such as [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) or [Flajaxian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222330/multiple-file-selection-for-uploading-in-asp-net) seems to work in IE8, but authentication is apparently broken/not supported in the POST request generated by Flash in Firefox or Chrome (it always sends anonymous requests).
- Using HTML5 to do multi-file picking would be great, but wouldn't support IE8 or IE9.
- Out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seven years later, the need to support IE9 has dwindled to almost nothing, so I'd say the best answer is to use HTML5 Multi-file picking: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/02/28/Working-with-HTML5s-multiple-file-upload-support

Answer (score 0):

Why not authenticate before you even get to the upload page/area?

Once "logged in" you set a server side session variable and show the uploader.

On your image upload page check for that session variable, if it is set properly proceed with saving the file, if not return an error in a format your uploader will understand.

On a side note, I've used [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for multiple file uploading, worked great for me.

Comment: We would like to stick to Integrated Windows Authentication if possible.